# Why does my code give me segmentation error?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void concatena(char *, char *, char *);
void conta_consonanti(char [], int *);
void copy_string(char [], char [ ], int);

int main(void) {
    char *input1, *input2, *output;
    input1 = "sdaeteruiop";
    input2 = "eiyearteoiana";
    concatena(input1, input2, output);
    printf("%s\n", output);
    free(output);
    return 0;
}

void concatena(char *input1, char *input2, char *output) {
    int num_cons1 = 0, num_cons2 = 0, dim_input1, dim_input2;
    conta_consonanti(input1, &num_cons1);
    conta_consonanti(input2, &num_cons2);
    if (num_cons1 < num_cons2) {
        dim_input1 = strlen(input1) + strlen(input2);
        output = malloc(dim_input1 * sizeof(char));
        copy_string(output, input1, 0);
        copy_string(output, input2, strlen(input1));
    } else if (num_cons2 < num_cons1) {
        dim_input2 = strlen(input2) + strlen(input1);
        output = malloc(dim_input2 * sizeof(char));
        copy_string(output, input2, 0);
        copy_string(output, input1, strlen(input2));
    }
}

void conta_consonanti(char vect[], int *num_cons) {
    int dim = strlen(vect), i;
    for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        if (vect[i] != 'a' && vect[i] != 'e' && vect[i] != 'i' && vect[i] != 'o' && vect[i] != 'u')
            *num_cons++;
}

void copy_string(char output[], char input [ ], int offset) {
    int dim, i;
    dim = strlen(input);
    for (i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        output[offset] = input[i];
        offset++;
    }
}
```

Why does my code give me segmentation error?

The program should join the two strings and store the resulting string in `output` but it gives me segmentation error. Why?

The string with fewer consonants is stored first.

Comment: `dim_input1 = strlen(input2) + strlen(input1);` and `dim_input2 = strlen(input2) + strlen(input1);`...you're short-by-one.

Comment: One other thing. A valid string may contain other characters than letters — punctuation, spaces, digits — and in that case your implementation of `conta_consonanti()` does not actually count consonants, but instead characters that are not vowels. This might seem like it's a trivial distinction but you can find problems in future when a function does something _like, but not quite_ what the name implies.

Comment: @TimRandall I thought about it, but the string in this context was without spaces

Answer (score 2):

in

```
 concatena(input1, input2, output);
 printf("%s\n", output);
```

the value of *output* is unchanged by *concatena* so you print an uninitialized char * => crash or any other undefined behavior

you need to make output an output var, so `void concatena(char *input1, char *input2, char **output)` etc like that :

```
int main(void){
    char *input1, *input2, *output;
    input1 = "sdaeteruiop";
    input2 = "eiyearteoiana";
    concatena(input1, input2, &output);
    printf("%s\n", output);
    free(output);
    return 0;
}

void concatena(char *input1, char *input2, char **output){
    int num_cons1 = 0, num_cons2 = 0, dim_input1, dim_input2;
    conta_consonanti(input1, &num_cons1);
    conta_consonanti(input2, &num_cons2);
    if(num_cons1 < num_cons2){
        dim_input1 = strlen(input1) + strlen(input2);
        *output = malloc(dim_input1 + 1);
        strcpy(*output, input1);
        strcat(*output, input2);
    }else {
        dim_input2 = strlen(input2) + strlen(input1);
        *output = malloc(dim_input2 + 1);
        strcpy(*output, input2);
        strcat(*output, input1);
    }
}
```

I also fixed your malloc, you missed 1 char for the null terminator

warning if `num_cons2 == num_cons1` *output is not set and you still print it not initialized, you need to set it to NULL and test that case before to printf it, or more probably to replace `else if(num_cons2 < num_cons1)` by `else` (this is what I did above)

note also `dim_input1` and `dim_input2` have the same value, it is useless to distinguishes them

and the first call of `copy_string` can be replaced by `strcpy` and the second by `strcat`, **except that `copy_string`miss to add a final null character**. I removed the use of `copy_string`

warning the declaration `void concatena(char *, char *, char *);` must be updated to be `void concatena(char *, char *, char **);`

Execution :

```
eiyearteoianasdaeteruiop
```

Under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ valgrind ./a.out
==15629== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15629== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==15629== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15629== Command: ./a.out
==15629== 
eiyearteoianasdaeteruiop
==15629== 
==15629== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15629==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15629==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,049 bytes allocated
==15629== 
==15629== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==15629== 
==15629== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15629== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187612/discussion-on-answer-by-bruno-why-does-my-code-give-me-segmentation-error).

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- You pass an uninitialized pointer for the destination array (3rd argument) of `concatena`. The API is incorrect: you should instead make `concatena` return the pointer to the newly allocated array as a return value.  The current implementation overwrites the 3rd argument `output` and this allocated value is never returned to the caller. C has no concept of *output* arguments, you could pass a pointer to the caller's `output` pointer, with type `char **`, but it is much simpler to just use the return value.
- The allocation performed by `concatena` is incorrect: you should allocate an extra byte for the null terminator and `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition:

  ```
  output = malloc(dim_input1 + 1);
  ```
- `conta_consonanti` is incorrect too: incrementing the number pointed to by `num_cons` must be written `++*num_cons` or `(*num_cons)++`. `*num_cons++;` increments the pointer, not the value pointed to. Furthermore, as Tom Randall commented, the number of consonants is not necessarily the same as the number of non-vowels as the string may contain non letters. Also you count all uppercase letters as consonants, which seems incorrect too.
- The code would have undefined behavior if both strings have the same number of consonants, you should specify what happens in this case (and implement it).
- `copy_string` does not set the null terminator in the destination buffer. Either set it there or set it manually in `concatena`.

Here is a corrected (and simplified) version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *concatena(const char *s1, const char *s2);
int conta_consonanti(const char *vect);
void copy_string(char *output, const char *intput);

int main(void) {
    const char *input1 = "sdaeteruiop";
    const char *input2 = "eiyearteoiana";
    char *output = concatena(input1, input2);
    printf("%s\n", output);
    free(output);
    return 0;
}

char *concatena(const char *input1, const char *input2) {
    int len1 = strlen(input1);
    int len2 = strlen(input2);
    int num_cons1 = conta_consonanti(input1);
    int num_cons2 = conta_consonanti(input2);
    char *output = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1);
    if (output != NULL) {
        if (num_cons1 <= num_cons2) {
            copy_string(output, input1, 0);
            copy_string(output, input2, len1);
        } else {
            copy_string(output, input2);
            copy_string(output, input1, len1);
        }
        output[len1 + len2] = '\0';  // set the null terminator
    }
    return output;
}

int conta_consonanti(const char *vect) {
    int i, num_cons = 0;
    for (i = 0; vect[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        /* counting ASCII consonants, upper and lowercase */
        /* our French friends will miss the ç and our Spanish ones the ñ */
        if (strchr("BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz", vect[i])
            num_cons++;
    }
    return num_cons;
}

void copy_string(char *output, const char *input, int offset) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        output[offset] = input[i];
        offset++;
    }
}
```

Comment: oh yes I didn't see the error in `*num_cons++;`, eagle eyes ^^

Comment: Possibly you could use fewer returns in this sentence: "make concatena return a pointer to the newly allocated array and return that as a return value"

Answer (score 0):

You try to free `output` in main, while it has no value assigned. The assignment in `concatena` is not returned to main. It would make more sense to return the allocated buffer from within `concatena` and assign it to `output`, then cleaning it up in the end.